# Fill in Dates for Table in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 and have the following issue:

I have a table of dates `table_dates`

```
+--------+
|  Date  |
+--------+
|20130401|
+--------+
|20130402|
+--------+
|   ...  |
+--------+
|20130830|
+--------+
```

And a table of total information `table_total`

```
+--------+--------+---------+
|  Date  |   ID   |  Total  |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130401|   Bob  |    1    |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130403|   Bob  |    6    |
+--------+--------+---------+
|   ...  |   ...  |   ...   |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130612|  Jill  |    2    |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

What I would like to do is create a new table `table_overall` such that we have a record for every `ID` in `table_total` and every date in `table_dates`. It should also contain a `total` column that is equal to the `total` in `table_total` with the same `ID` and the maximum `table_total.Date <= total.Date` i.e.

```
+--------+--------+---------+
|  Date  |   ID   |  Total  |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130401|   Bob  |    1    |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130402|   Bob  |    1    |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130403|   Bob  |    6    |
+--------+--------+---------+
|  ...   |   ...  |   ...   |
+--------+--------+---------+
|20130612|  Jill  |    2    |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

I've tried to use a query along the lines of

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS SELECT Date FROM table_dates;
CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS SEELCT ID FROM table_total GROUP BY ID;
CREATE TEMP Table t3 as SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2;

SELECT * FROM table_total as r 
INNER JOIN t3 as t ON 
(r.ID = t.ID AND (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM table_total WHERE Date < t.Date) = r.Date);
```

But it is far too slow and I'm not sure if it is even correct. What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use `TEMP TABLE` and do a unique query, try this to see if you have some gain in term of time of execution :

```
SELECT
    Date
    ,ID
    ,Total
FROM
    table_total
UNION
SELECT 
    td.Date
    ,tt.ID
    ,tt.Total
FROM
    table_total tt
    INNER JOIN table_dates td
        ON td.Date >= tt.Date
        AND td.Date < (SELECT MIN(tt2.Date) FROM table_total tt2 WHERE tt2.Date > tt.Date)
```

You didn't talk about it, but I can imagine you are using `SQLite` with mobile application and you need your new `table_overall` table to do some other queries... I suggest you to use a `VIEW` with that `SELECT` for any work around join/select because mobile devices are not designed to insert huge bulk of data.

I tested my query on **[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/23f75/19)**, I'm not sure if I did what you wanted to do so if you need some more help or to solve another issue, feel free to leave a comment above.